# How to Refresh Googlemap when Fusiontable updated?

Tags: google-maps, caching, google-fusion-tables

I'm using fusiontable on googlemap and I have some problem that I can't see updated marks on googlemap even though I updated fusiontable data.

i have tried following.

```
layer.setOptions({

  query: {

    select: 'latitude',

    from: 'tableId'

  }

});
```

I have tried all kind of browser and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, the tiles will be cached on serverside and also on clientside.

The common workaround is to create a random where-clause that doesn't affect the results, because it always evaluates to true.

Example:

```
query: {
          select: "latitude",
          from: "TableId",
          where: "latitude NOT EQUAL TO '"+new Date().getTime()+"'"
        }
```

(assuming `latitude` is a Location-column, whose value can never be an Integer
as returned by `new Date().getTime()`)

The drawback of this approach is that you disable caching at all, what may impair the performance of your application.

A better solution would be to store the timestamp for the last modification on serverside and apply it to the where-clause instead of the JS-generated timestamp.